# value of $c$ and $d$ in $g(c)=d$

Tags: calculus

> Consider the function $g(x)=2x-\cos(x)+1$ on $x\in[0,1]$.
>
> The intermediate value theorem guarantees that there is a value of $c$ such that $g(c)=d.$ Then the interval in which $c,d$ lies, is?

What I have tried:

Let $g(x)=2x-\cos x+1$

Then $g'(x)=2+\sin x>0$ for $x\in[0,1]$

So function $g(x)$ is strictly increasing

And $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=3-\cos 1\approx 2.4596$

So $g(c)=d$ means $c\in[0,1]$ and $d\in[0,3-\cos 1]$

Is my solution right? If not then please tell me how should I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Seems right to me.

Comment: It looks right to me, though I would explicitly note that g(x) is differentiable before differentiating it.